# Method run it 3 times

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Metoder {

public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Skriv inn navn: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Skriv in bosted: ");
        String place = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hei, " +name+ "! Du er fra " +place);


    }
}
```

How can I make it run 3 times with the method?
P.S. its Norwegian and it is asking a person's name and living place. So I need it to ask for 3 person.

Comment: [Use a loop such as for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) or while.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Metoder {

public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       for(int i=0; i<3; i++){   
        System.out.println("Skriv inn navn: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Skriv in bosted: ");
        String place = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hei, " +name+ "! Du er fra " +place);
       }


    }
}
```

Comment: why you need to create Scanner each time?